# Какие существуют отличие библиотек от плагинов wordpress для создания слайдеров?

Tags: wordpress

Нужно сделать слайдер (адаптивный и со своими стрелками) но не могу понять, какие отличия есть у плагинов на wordpress и библиотек для создания слайдеров(slick или swiper к примеру)?

Comment: Всё просто. Если библиотеку привести в порядок и оформить нужным образом - получится плагин :) https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще это палка о двух концах (и конечно же зависит от того, разработчик вы или простой пользователь).

Используя плагин, у вас уже есть некий интерфейс, все выведено в админку, имеет какие-то настройки, фичи и тп, все работает уже out of the box, и грубо говоря, вам нужно накликать некоторые настройки, и вывести слайдер с помощью шорткода или блока.

При работе с библиотеками, главное -- гибкость. Как минимум когда вы работаете с Slick, Swiper, Glide либо чем-то другим, вы можете использовать все возможности библиотеки на полную катушку. К примеру, используя тот же ACF PRO, вы можете вывести и использовать все необходимые вам опции в админке и сделать все в точности как именно вам нужно, все опции и фичи.

В тоже время, плагин слайдера накладывает на вас определенные ограничения, грубо говоря, вы ограничены возможностями самого плагина, а когда вам нужно будет что-то расширить или выйти где-то «за рамки», не факт что разработчик плагина заложил такую возможность.

Есть небольшие и легковесные плагинчики, а есть прямо монстры, подобные комбайну, по своим возможностям, я не говорю сейчас о технической стороне данных решений, но к примеру, на Slider Revolution можно хоть сайты строить, я конечно утрирую, но возможностей там прямо очень много, но в этом зачастую и проблема (так как разработчики таких решений пытаются угодить всем и сразу), там будет слишком много всего лишнего, слишком много оверхеда, лишних скриптов, стилей и фич, которыми вы даже скорее всего никогда и не воспользуетесь, что так же в свою очередь не очень хорошо скажется на скорости работы вашего сайта.

Если вы разработчик, то всегда проще работать именно с библиотекой, если же вы совсем технически не подкованы, то тогда проще будет воспользоваться плагином, при условии что вы найдете именно тот, который удовлетворит ваши потребности.